# How to measure performance (consumed memory) of apache2 and nginx?

Tags: performance, memory, nginx, apache2, measure

I want to measure performance of the apache2 and nginx servers.

As a result I expect charts like on this [website](http://blog.webfaction.com/2008/12/a-little-holiday-present-10000-reqssec-with-nginx-2/).

I can measure *request per second* using following tools: [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/), [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html), [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) but how to measure the memory consumed by these servers?

I found [this site](http://foertsch.name/ModPerl-Tricks/Measuring-memory-consumption/index.shtml) but I don't know if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ab.c](http://gwan.ch/source/ab.c) open-source program does it (per-process, per-thread, etc.), see an [example of report here](http://gwan.ch/en_apachebench_httperf.html#100.html), a [comparison between two servers there](http://gwan.ch/en_apachebench_httperf.html#wrk2) (the point of your question) showing [how much memory usage can differ](http://gwan.ch/faq#cclients) depending on servers and configuration options.

Comment: Thank you very much! AB.C program does exactly what I want.
Maybe you can look also at following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088044/running-web2py-on-g-wan-generally-pythons-framework-on-g-wan