# Running Web2Py on G-WAN (generally Python's framework on G-WAN)

Tags: python, web2py, uwsgi, g-wan

Yesterday I have found information about [G-WAN](http://gwan.com/) server.

I have searched many websites but I couldn't discover how to run frameworks like Web2Py which is more complex then simple `hello.py` file.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Maybe uWSGI support?

Answer (score 0):

G-WAN supports the `CGI interface`, so the `CGI environment variables` are already there. Usually, Web frameworks are built over this layer.

If `uWSGI` provides more environment variables ***that are needed for your project*** then please drop us a line at gwan.com to explain more precisely what you need.

Comment: Can you look at http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Deployment-recipes?
`web2py provides a file cgihandler.py to interface to CGI.`
How to connect g-wan CGI interface with cgihandler.py of web2py?
There are also FastCGI, WSGI and others.

Comment: I am not a Python developer so I can't answer this question.